# Realm: can't parse 110k objects on real android device

Tags: android, realm, retrofit2

Essentially the question was in title. In detail: I am using Realm for storing 
users in device storage. I am doing one request to server which returns list with 110k objects, gson parses this, all actions from out of memory were done. On emulator this operation continues for about 3 minutes and all saved to db successfully. All json data is valid, if it wasn't, on emulator it would crashed too.  **But,** when I checked on real android device I got this

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at line 2 column 3 path $[70816].info2000
```

when gson was trying to parse 70816 object it couldn't, because it's not valid. I re-checked this user in database. All was good. I ran again and got this exception on another object

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 2 column 1091 path $[56000].accountCrm
```

So it's randomly.
I got confused and began researching, and I couldn't find anything. These objects come in response body(okhttp), I parse it like this:

```
Gson gson = GsonBase.getGlobalGson();
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(responseBody.charStream()); //these are my 110k objects
    reader.setLenient(true);
    reader.beginArray();
    List<ContactCRMRealm> contactCRMRBuffer = new ArrayList<>();
    int counter = 0;
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        if (counter < BUFFER_SIZE) {
            contactCRMRBuffer.add(gson.fromJson(reader, ContactCRMRealm.class));
            counter++;
        } else {
            defaultInstance.executeTransaction(realm1 -> realm1.insertOrUpdate(contactCRMRBuffer));
            counter = 0;
            contactCRMRBuffer.clear();
        }
    }
    defaultInstance.executeTransaction(realm1 -> realm1.insertOrUpdate(contactCRMRBuffer));
    contactCRMRBuffer.clear();
    reader.endArray();
```

Exceptions are thrown in this line:

```
contactCRMRBuffer.add(gson.fromJson(reader, ContactCRMRealm.class));
```

I can't figure out but It seems like response body is being broken unexpectedly. Why It works on emulator and doesn't on android device? Few things that I can say: when I comment this line in else block:

```
defaultInstance.executeTransaction(realm1 -> realm1.insertOrUpdate(contactCRMRBuffer));
```

all parsing side was performed without exceptions. I think it's because of realm. But what exactly? I re-wrote this parsing using createOrUpdateAllFromJson() realm method:

```
defaultInstance.beginTransaction();
    try {
        defaultInstance.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(ContactCRMRealm.class, responseBody.byteStream());
        defaultInstance.commitTransaction();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        defaultInstance.close();
    } finally {
        defaultInstance.close();
    }
```

On emulator was out of memory(wtf), on real device nothing happened for 10 minutes and login exception was thrown(read timeout 10 minutes).Also I was trying to make offset, by 10 thousands users on one request, nothing changed. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a day of investigation, the problem was solved. Realm was 2.3.0 version in the app(yes, really old), so I was thinking maybe need to upgrade to newer verison. I did it, I upgraded realm to 3.7.0(not the last one because rxjava1 is using in the app). That's it. There are a lot of improvements, especially speed improvements, so now all is fine.